# Horizontal scroll bar displays on website even after CSS Reset

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have superfluous/erroneous width on my website even after a CSS Reset that displays the horizontal scroll bar. I am using Boostrap 3.0 and can't seem to find any broken HTML, notice too it is on every page of the website. I tried a "heavy" CSS reset and that didn't even fix the issue.

[This is the website](http://www.homevana.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has to do with not using the bootstrap container class to create your site in.

`<div class="content container">` in the footer fixes the problem without doing anything else.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container

Bootstrap adds a negative left and right margin on .row classes to counter-act with the 15px padding added to the .container class. If you don't use the .container class you are left with the negative margin on your 100% width .row.

```
<footer role="contentinfo" id="footer">
            <div class="content container">
                <div class="row">
```

Comment: Thanks I used content instead of container!! Don't even have a content class.

Answer (score 2):

Check the width of your footer, containing `How it Works` and your social icons. My tools show its width exceeding the other elements.

[image]

[Direct Image Link (Full Size)](http://oi44.tinypic.com/2wm1kdw.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

`<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-push-1">` has a width of `1197px`, which is causing there to be extra white space on the right.

[image]